# Best effort (failover) HTTP proxy use in aptitude?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, http, squid, aptitude

I was installing a new Ubuntu 13.10 (daily build) for testing, and came to the option of being able to configure an HTTP proxy server for aptitude. It's been a while since I've sat through an installer and not just cloned a system, and the idea crossed my mind of using our existing HTTP proxy in front of aptitude, to speed up the package update process and reduce bandwidth consumption; however I don't want all of the servers to be incapacitated in the event of a failure on the proxy server, since it is a single point of failure.

I want to configure aptitude to use the existing HTTP proxy, but go around the proxy if it doesn't respond. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: How many systems do you have?  It might be easier to simply install something like [approx](http://packages.debian.org/sid/approx), on the host that is your proxy, then update the `sources.list` to point to your local proxy in addition to the upstream Ubuntu servers.  Sources are tried in order.

Comment: @Zoredache Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I'm unofficially accepting your comment as the correct answer.